# Why is IDLE auto-indenting by a massive four tabs? Each tab appears to be 8 spaces, so it's indenting by 32 spaces

Tags: python, python-idle

When I hit `return`, I get an indent (actually the opposite of an indent, more of an outdent) of four tabs:

[image: FOUR TABS]

Worse than this, it seems that each tab is 8 spaces, so that the resulting indent is humungous.
Why is this?  My settings seem to indicate four spaces, although there is no option to switch between spaces and tabs that I can see.
I'm using version 3.6.4.
Contents of `.idlerc\config-main.cfg`:

```
[Keys]
name = Key Set 1
default = False
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: One of the tabs shown using mouse click-drag:

[image]

There are 4 of those.

Comment: It's 32 spaces; possibly 31

Comment: what is in your ~/.idlerc/config-main.cfg?

Comment: what version of idle is that? i cant get it to reproduce in mine ... with all of 2 minutes of trying

Comment: I can't find a file called config-main.cfg. I'm on windows, BTW. Where might it be?

Comment: The version is 3.6.4

Comment: Probably in your user directory -- so like `C:\Users\<your username>\.idlerc\config-main.cfg`  It may be hidden?  I'm not near a Windows box atm

Comment: Here is, thanks: `[Keys]
name = Key Set 1
default = False`

Comment: I put a few more minutes into trying to reproduce it and I, too am jumping onto the consider-a-better-ide train.  For me, IDLE apparently puts tabs in, so...

Comment: I get the "get a better IDE" thing. I just wanted to check if there was an easy fix/solution, etc. What is a good lightweight IDE?  Using Eclipse with a plugin seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: If I may step in - `Spyder` is a well working IDE imo. It's part of `WinPython` and afaik of several other distributions, too.

Comment: Thanks @SpghttCd but the WinPython download is 444.6 MB.  Not so much a sledgehammer, more of a piledriver...

Comment: I've just realised that I installed Anaconda3 a while ago; I'm using Spyder now for the first time and I'm happy with it. Thanks.

Comment: @jedwards Try `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: I have used IDLE for over a decade and now help maintain it and I have never seen anything like this or a report like this.  Which version of Windows?  Which binary?  Please copy the first line IDLE displays.  I just installed 3.6.4 and see "Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32".  Have you tried upgrading to a newer Python/IDLE release?  Did you try switching back to the default Windows keyset instead of your custom keyset?

Comment: @jedwards Did you reproduce the reported behavior or not?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I couldn't get the 8 space tabs, no.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy `Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`  I have been using Spyder for the last 24 hours, but being notified of new comments on this question has prompted me to check the behaviour is still occurring, and when starting IDLE up I am now not seeing it. I have no clue why the issue occurred; I had changed no settings (there is only one setting to change and that was already on 4 (which means presumably 4 spaces). So it will probably be forever a mystery.

Comment: IDLE had a bug such that repeatedly entering code with certain kinds of syntax errors caused the automatic indents to grow.  This *might* have been the problem here.  This bug was fixed after 3.6.8/3.7.2 were released.  The fix will be in 3.7.3.  https://bugs.python.org/issue34055